# Indexer Issue // DB CONSTRAINT

Tags: database, reindex

I am getting following Error on reindexing:

```
       Product Attributes index process unknown error:
    exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity 
constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`databasename`.`catalog_product_index_eav`, CONSTRAINT 
`FK_CAT_PRD_IDX_EAV_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY 
(`entity_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE
 CASCA)' in .../lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
```

How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

try this. good luck

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111889/cant-re-index-new-products-after-upgrading-to-version-1-6/19837851#19837851

```
delete FROM `catalog_product_entity_datetime` where entity_id not in (select entity_id from catalog_product_entity);
delete FROM `catalog_product_entity_decimal` where entity_id not in (select entity_id from catalog_product_entity);
delete FROM `catalog_product_entity_gallery` where entity_id not in (select entity_id from catalog_product_entity);
delete FROM `catalog_product_entity_group_price` where entity_id not in (select entity_id from catalog_product_entity);
delete FROM `catalog_product_entity_int` where entity_id not in (select entity_id from catalog_product_entity);
delete FROM `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` where entity_id not in (select entity_id from catalog_product_entity);
delete FROM `catalog_product_entity_text` where entity_id not in (select entity_id from catalog_product_entity);
delete FROM `catalog_product_entity_tier_price` where entity_id not in (select entity_id from catalog_product_entity);
delete FROM `catalog_product_entity_varchar` where entity_id not in (select entity_id from catalog_product_entity);
#originals with formatting fixed:
delete from `catalog_category_product` WHERE product_id not in(select entity_id from catalog_product_entity);
delete from `catalog_category_product` WHERE category_id not in(select entity_id from catalog_category_entity); 
delete from `catalog_product_website` WHERE product_id not in(select entity_id from catalog_product_entity); 
delete from `catalog_product_index_eav_idx` WHERE entity_id not in(select entity_id from catalog_product_entity); 
delete from `catalog_product_index_eav` WHERE entity_id not in(select entity_id from catalog_product_entity); 
delete from `catalog_product_link` WHERE product_id not in(select entity_id from catalog_product_entity); 
delete from `catalog_product_relation` WHERE parent_id not in(select entity_id from catalog_product_entity);
```